# Javascript: Checkbox that changes immediately on the website for all users, without updating the webpage

Tags: javascript, html

my first question in here.

I've just started learning JavaScript and i would like to make a "checkbox" on a website that changes live.
What i mean is a checkbox that one person can check on the website from his computer, and then the other person from another computer sees the change immediately without updating the webpage.

Comment: https://socket.io/

Comment: Read about Websocket. It's not an easy topic for beginners though.